# What is a pointer? Like literally, what is it?

Tags: pointers

I know what pointers do, that they point to a specific memory location. But what is the actual thing that is pointing to that memory location?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pointer is an integer holding the memory address to whatever it points to.

Comment: This is right on from what I understand, but I'd supplement it with this specific explanation from pointers in C: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#C_pointers

It helps me to conceptualize both the memory address and the contents of the memory address.

Comment: True. And that's the reason why in some languages *pointer arithmetic* is possible.